# Add/edit values in a multidimensional array using an array of key names

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of key names of variable length and I want to use those names to assign a value to an array

for example, I have an array that lists the number of cars and bikes of different makes:

```
$vehicles = [
    'cars' => Array
    (
        'suzuki' => Array
        (
            'wagon' => 4,
            'baleno' => 2
        ),
        'honda' => Array
        (
            'civic' => 6
        )
    ),
    'bikes' => array
    (
        'raleigh' => 3,
        'scott' => 3
    )
];
```

I also have several arrays of key names along with values to put in the main array:

```
$keys1 = ['cars', 'honda', 'jazz'];
$value1 = 3;
$keys2 = ['bikes', 'scott'];
$value2 = 1;
$keys3 = ['motorbikes', 'harley-davidson', 'dyna', 'street-bob'];
$value3 = 2;
```

After inputting all these values the array should look like this:

```
$vehicles = [
    'cars' => Array
    (
        'suzuki' => Array
        (
            'wagon' => 4,
            'baleno' => 2
        ),
        'honda' => Array
        (
            'civic' => 6,
            'jazz' => 3
        )
    ),
    'bikes' => array
    (
        'raleigh' => 3,
        'scott' => 1
    ),
    'motorbikes' => Array
    (
        'harley-davidson' => Array
        (
            'dyna' => Array
            (
                'street-bob' => 2
            )
        )
    )
];
```

So the first array adds a `$key => $value` pair where there wasn't one before. The second one replaces the value of the key at the end of `$array2` and the last one creates a new array when there isn't one to begin with.

How can I populate the array in this way?

`eval()` would solve all my problems but the arrays are created from html and so it is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform your `$keys` array in the same format as your `$vehicles` and then replace them recursively :

```
$vehicles = [
    'cars' => [
        'suzuki' => [
            'wagon'  => 1,
            'boleno' => 2
        ]
    ],

    'bikes' => [
        'scott' => 3
    ]

];

$keys = ['cars', 'honda', 'jazz'];
$value  = 3;

function addValues($vehicles, $keys, $value)
{
    $formatted = formatArray($keys, $value);

    return array_replace_recursive($vehicles, $formatted);
}

function formatArray($array, $value)
{
    $format = function ($carry, $item) {
        return [$item => $carry];
    };

    return array_reduce(array_reverse($array), $format, $value);
}

$vehicles = addValues($vehicles, $keys, $value);
var_dump($vehicles);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  'cars' => 
    array (size=2)
      'suzuki' => 
        array (size=2)
          'wagon' => int 1
          'boleno' => int 2
      'honda' => 
        array (size=1)
          'jazz' => int 3
  'bikes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'scott' => int 3
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.
I couldn't figure out why array_merge was there so I tested it without and it did the same thing but 5 times slower. Could you tell me why that is?

Comment: @ChrisStarling You are welcome, I'm glad to help. You don't really need it there. It's actually faster without it. I was previously testing with a second array, so it's just a leftover. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The convenient way(on my opinion) to construct a key/value pairs list would be as the following:

```
// $vehicles is your initial array

$key_paths = [
  ['key_path' =>  ['cars', 'honda', 'jazz'], 'value' => 3],
  ['key_path' =>  ['bikes', 'scott'], 'value' => 1],
  ['key_path' =>  ['motorbikes', 'harley-davidson', 'dyna', 'street-bob'], 'value' => 2],
];
```

And here is the solution using `array_slice` function and *references*:

```
foreach ($key_paths as $kPath) {
    $current = null;
    foreach (array_slice($kPath['key_path'], 0, -1) as $key) {
        if (is_null($current)) {
            if (!isset($vehicles[$key])) $vehicles[$key] = [];
            $current = &$vehicles[$key];
        } else {
            if (!isset($current[$key])) $current[$key] = [];
            $current = &$current[$key];
        }
    }
    $current[end($kPath['key_path'])] = $kPath['value'];
    unset($current);    // unsetting reference
}

print_r($vehicles);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [cars] => Array
        (
            [suzuki] => Array
                (
                    [wagon] => 4
                    [baleno] => 2
                )

            [honda] => Array
                (
                    [civic] => 6
                    [jazz] => 3
                )
        )

    [bikes] => Array
        (
            [raleigh] => 3
            [scott] => 1
        )

    [motorbikes] => Array
        (
            [harley-davidson] => Array
                (
                    [dyna] => Array
                        (
                            [street-bob] => 2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you.
A follow up question:
How could one unset specific keys in the array if unset($current) only removes the reference?

Comment: you can *unset specific keys in the array*  by specifying a certain key directly (e.g. `unset($vehicles['cars']['honda'])`) or by iterating through an array  (e.g. `foreach($vehicles as $k => $v){  if($k == 'bikes') unset($vehicles[$k]); }`)